# Problem with JHipster app generation - conflict between two created app on the server port

Tags: jhipster

I generated two apps using jhipster command. One for a Jhipster demo called Blog and the other one called MyFarm.

In blog, there were three entities: Blog, Entry and Tag

In MyFarm there are two entities: Farm and Product.

The first app Blog works properly. Then I stop it. I open and run the new App myFarm and it keeps trying to reach the Blog entities... that it doesn't find obviously and then I get an error.

To generate the entities I used the import of a jh file containing the following:

```js
entity Farm {
name String required minlength(3),
details TextBlob required
}

entity Product {
type String required,
quality Quality required,
quantity Integer required,
date Instant required
}


relationship ManyToOne {
Farm {user(login)} to User,
Product{farm(name)} to Farm
}

paginate Product with infinite-scroll

enum Quality {
MAUVAISE, BONNE, EXCELLENTE
}
```

The entities have been generated properly then. But they are in red in my IDE and the App doesn't try to reachc those entities upon running.

Does somebody have a clue, please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The port is configured in the `.yo-rc.json` file in each project, edit one and change value of `serverPort` property, then re-generate your app by executing `jhipster`.